# State_Machine VHDL Code, can you please check why it doesn't work ! it synthesises ok

Tags: vhdl, state-machine

i have an assignment to write a state machine in VHDL to take control of a small built MC ( consists of 4 flip-flops,2 MUX4to1, MUX1to4, ROM, ALU,Inport ).

i have written different codes and tried several methods however simulating it shows no results, i get 'U' for results.

Code below, please check for obvious errors which I've probably missed.
i think the problem is that the stjatemachine doesn't transition through the states or doesn't execute the code inside each state.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    07:48:47 10/26/2014 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    STATE_MACHINE - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity STATE_MACHINE is
port (

        --General Ports
        CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
        Re_Run_Programme : in STD_LOGIC;

        --Process A parts
        Programme_Start : in STD_LOGIC;
        Data_From_ROM   : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        ADDR_To_ROM : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0);
        Programme_Status: out STD_LOGIC;
        EN_OUT : out STD_LOGIC;

        --Process B Part


        --Process C Parts

        MUX_FF_Select : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);

        MUX1_Select : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);  
        MUX2_Select : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
        ALU_Select  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);

        EN_A_Ports : out STD_LOGIC;
        EN_B_Ports : out STD_LOGIC;

        BUS_Select : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
        Reset      : out STD_LOGIC



    ); 
end STATE_MACHINE;

architecture Behavioral of STATE_MACHINE is

type State_Type is (State_A,State_B,State_C,State_D);
signal State,Next_State : State_Type;

signal Counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0);

--signal MO_A : STD_LOGIC;
--signal MO_B : STD_LOGIC;
--signal MO_C : STD_LOGIC;
--signal MO_D : STD_LOGIC;

signal FF_Instruction : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);          -- 00
signal MUX_ALU_Instruction : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);         -- 01
signal BUS_A_B_Ports_Instruction : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);   -- 10
signal Reset_Instruction : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0); 

signal FF_Path : STD_LOGIC;
signal MUX_ALU_Path : STD_LOGIC;
signal BUS_A_B_Ports_Path : STD_LOGIC;
signal Reset_Path : STD_LOGIC;

signal EN_OUT_reg : STD_LOGIC;

--signal Next_Call : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
signal Instruction_Finder : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
signal Instruction_Identifier : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal Instruction : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal Call_Next_Instruction : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0);


begin



FF_Instruction        <= "00000000";
MUX_ALU_Instruction       <= "01000000";
BUS_A_B_Ports_Instruction <= "10000000";
Reset_Instruction         <= "11000000";

Instruction_Finder <= "11000000";

Counter <= "000000";
Call_Next_Instruction <= "000000";


--Re Run the programme
Process(CLK)
begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        if (Re_Run_Programme = '1') then
            State <= State_A;
--          MO_A <= '0';
            else 
            State <= Next_State;
        end if;
    end if;
end Process;

--next state 
Process(CLK,State)
begin

Next_State <= State;

case State is


--#### STATE A #####
    when State_A =>

    --if falling_edge(CLK) then

            ADDR_To_ROM <= Call_Next_Instruction;
            --EN_OUT <= '1';
            --if falling_edge (CLK) then
                --Instruction <= DATA_From_ROM;
            --end if;
    Next_State <= State_B;

    --end if;


--#### STATE B #####
    when State_B =>
    EN_OUT <= '1';
                Instruction <= DATA_From_ROM;

        Instruction_Identifier <= (Instruction and Instruction_Finder);
        case (Instruction_Identifier) is
            when "00000000" => FF_Path <= '1';
            when "01000000" => MUX_ALU_Path <= '1';
            when "10000000" => BUS_A_B_Ports_Path <= '1';
            when "11000000" => Reset_Path <= '1';
            when others => null;
        end case;
        Next_State <= State_C after 40ns;

--#### STATE C #####

    when State_C =>

        --########
        if ((FF_Path = '1') and (Counter = 2)) then
            MUX_FF_Select <= "00";
        end if;
        if ((FF_Path = '1') and (Counter = 4)) then
            MUX_FF_Select <= "00" after 20ns;
        end if;

        --########

        if (falling_edge(CLK) and (MUX_ALU_Path = '1')) then
            MUX1_Select <= "00";
            MUX2_Select <= "00";
        end if;

        --########

        if ( rising_edge(CLK) and BUS_A_B_Ports_Path = '1') then
            if Counter = 1 then
                BUS_Select <= "01";
            end if;
            if Counter = 3 then
                BUS_Select <= "10";
            end if;
            EN_A_Ports <= '1';
            EN_B_Ports <= '1';
        end if;

        --########

        if ( rising_edge(CLK) and Reset_Path = '1') then
        Reset <= '1';
        end if;

        Next_State <= State_D after 60ns;

--#### STATE D #####

    when State_D =>


        EN_OUT <= '0';
        Counter <= Counter + 1;

        if Counter > 5 then     
            Next_State <= State_D;
        end if;

        Call_Next_Instruction <= Counter;

        Next_State <= State_A;


    end case;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

github link to code: https://github.com/quasarMind/StateMachine.git

Comment: This will never synthesize properly: `Next_State <= State_D after 60ns;` You're also using the `falling_edge` and `rising_edge` of a clock, which can be very difficult to synthesize.

Comment: Rewrite the second process in proper synchronous form, like the first process. Better, roll them both into a single process state machine.

Comment: @BillLynch it seems that it isn't a good practice to use both rising and falling edge, I'm new to VHDL, but can you shed some light on this matter, because i would need to output commands that aren't on the same clock event, so how would it be possible to execute on operation then sequentially the other on the next clock even, thanks !

Comment: @DavidKoontz how would it be possible to initialise a signal and then change its value, I've tried using "variable" but got a lot of errors then. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Besides comments by Bill Lynch and Brian Drummond addressing synthesis eligibility a reason why the model gets all 'U's appears to revolve around multiple drivers for 
`Instruction_Finder`, `Counter` and `Call_Next_Instruction`. One driver is initialized the other delivering all 'U's, the two resolve to all 'U's.

For purposes of simulating to see what your state machine actually does (and sidestepping the issue of synthesis), set default values for these three signals in their declarations and comment out the additional concurrent signal assignment statements, e.g.:

```
signal Counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0) := (others => '0');

signal Instruction_Finder : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := "11000000";

signal Call_Next_Instruction : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0) := (others => '0');


-- Instruction_Finder <= "11000000";
-- Counter <= "000000";
-- Call_Next_Instruction <= "000000";
```

Most synthesis vendors will honor default values for signals for FPGA targets, otherwise you can add a reset.